# How to update a program (exe) from internet using win32

Tags: winapi, replace, exe, uac

I've written a Win32 program that at regular intervals retrieves content from a dedicated server on the internet.

Sometimes the Win32 program itself needs to be updated. What I do is exit the said program and run a download-program which replaces the main exe I need to uopdate. This works for users running in Administrator mode but not other mode that has sufficent rights for most tasks. The program runs on it own directory which is not under "c:\Windows\program files\".

I've set a manifest file to no avail.

Is there a workable workaround solution for this (any)?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you cannot place files in Program Files without admin rights. If you would be able to this you could in theory change Windows files and place malware as well.
Same goes for Linux and OSX systems.
However you could [prompt the user for an Administrator password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717802(v=vs.85).aspx) and gain the admin rights in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need your updater program to have admin rights. You achieve that by adding the `requireAdministrator` option in the `requestedExecutionLevel` section of the application manifest. You said that you have tried this to no avail. Well, you must have got something wrong because this is the solution. You just need to persevere until you get the manifest correct.

I presume that when you say that the [program is not under the `Program Files` directory you refer to the updater. If the program being updated is not under the `Program Files` directory then there would seem to be no obvious reason that the updater needs admin rights. If that is so then you need to investigate further.

Comment: I've added requireAdministrator option in the requestedExecutionLevel section. Is there a utility I could use to report what manifest etc I have in my exe if the is some problem in compiling & linking?

Comment: A resource editor like Resource Hacker will let you view linked resources.